# equations with linear coefficients and exact equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation
 $$(-3x+y+6)dx+(x+y+2)dy=0$$
Is both an exact equation and an equation with linear coefficients. If solved like an exact equation I get a different answer than if solved as an exact equation. Why? Which is correct? If solved as an exact equation i get 
$$\mathbb C=xy+\dfrac {y^2}{2}+2y-\dfrac {3x^2}{2}+6x$$
If solved as an eq.with linear coefficients i get
 $$\mathbb C=(y+3)^2+2(x-1)(y+3)-3(x-1)^2$$
Also why are they different? Please explain. And how can I prove that they are the same if they are the same?

Comment: I would expand your second equation then divide both sides by 2 you know to show the solutions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

That is I would do this: So we have $(y+3)^2+2(x-1)(y+3)-3(x-1)^2=K$ Expand. $y^2+6y+9+2xy+6x-2y-6-3x^2+6x-3=K$ Now combine any like terms and I will also reordered some things. $2xy+y^2+4y-3x^2+12x=K$. Now divide both sides by 2. $xy+\frac{y^2}{2}+2y-\frac{3x^2}{2}+6x=\frac{K}{2}$. Your constant $C$ in the first equation is my constant $\frac{K}{2}$. Therefore the solutions are the same.